# Реализация выпадающего списка класса

Tags: c#, ооп, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Есть у меня класс с полем `Commisioning`, Commisioning имеет 3 значения:

```
"c 1994"
"до 1994"
"с 1.07.1995"
```

есть у него метод, получения этих самых значений значений, данный метод я использую для формирования выпадающего списка на `VIEW`.

```
 public class ThermLossesDataInputWaterPipeline
 {
    [Display(Name = "Год ввода в эксплуатацию")]
     public string Commissioning { get; set; }   


     public List<string> getSelectListCommisioning()
     {
          List<string> selectListCommisioning = new List<string>() { "до 1994", "с 1994", "с 1.07.1995" };
          return selectListCommisioning.ToList();
     }
 }
```

Во так выглядит `select` во `View`

```
  <select class="form-control" name="Commissioning" id="commissioning" asp-items="@new SelectList(Model.ThermLossesDataInputWaterPipeline.getSelectListCommisioning())"></select>
```

Есть класс, с расчетом каких-либо данных, куда передается значение `Commisioning` со View в этот расчетный класс,в зависимости от выбранного значения. В данный момент в расчетном классе есть куски кода:

```
  if (Commisioning == "c 1994"){}
```

Что есть плохо, т.к если я поменяю в моделе значение Commisioning, мне придется еще в 10 местах программы менять это значение. Я пытаюсь уйти от такого с помощью конструкции:

```
ThermLossesDataInputWaterPipeline thermLossesDataInputWaterPipeline = new ThermLossesDataInputWaterPipeline();

    if (Commisioning = thermLossesDataInputWaterPipeline.getSelectListCommisioning()[0]){}
```

Что бы уйти от явного сравнения строк, но мне кажется этот подход также не верен. Как правильно реализовать данный кусок кода, что можно использовать? Была мысль реализовать это как-то с помощью Enum, но не представляю как это сделать и можно ли через Enum.

Comment: а для чего вам этот метод getSelectListCommisioning вообще? почему не сделать этот класс моделью и описать там три свойтсва: From и Till (datetime)?

Comment: @pashagoroshko я использую этот метод в представлениях, в виде выпадающего списка. 
<select class="form-control" name="Commissioning" id="commissioning" asp-items="@new SelectList(Model.getSelectListCommisioning)"></select>  И этот класс является моделью.

Comment: Через Enum можно - там есть метод ToString(), но только для элементов, которые компилятор может распознать, как "правильный идентификатор". Очень плохо, что Вы сразу не сформировали свой вопрос в интерпретируемой форме.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов можно пример такого Enum?

Comment: Ну например так ' public enum MyEnum
    {
        до_1994,
        с_1994,
        с_1_07_1995
    } ',  и обращение     MyEnum q = MyEnum.с_1_07_1995;
    string strItemEnumName = q.ToString();
 - но я не советую

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов какой вариант реализации применить? Оставить выбор по индексу? Просто реально ситуация была, когда со временем, изменились название вводных данных, а все завязано на string значении... вообщем надо какой-то способ абстрагироваться от значений.

Comment: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740638/using-enum-for-dropdown-list-in-asp-net-mvc-core), [два](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-enum-aspnet-5-select-taghelper/), [три](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/10.4.php)